# Layout to Layout Transition with non-trivial UICollectionView use case

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

#### Context

I'm using the following Page Menu structure for my app:

- A top-level `UICollectionView` (Outer CV) driven by a `UICollectionViewController`
- 4 `UICollectionViewCell` instances, each with its own layout
- One of the cells contains a `UICollectionView` (inner CV)
- Tapping / Selecting one of the cells of the inner CV pushes another `UICollectionViewController`

See diagram below: [image: non-trivial UICollectionView layout]

#### Problem

I want to perform a Layout-to-Layout transition between the UICollectionViewControllers: either Outer CV / Inner CV and the pushed UICollectionViewController.

To that, I'm setting the `useLayoutToLayoutNavigationTransitions` flag to `YES` but it is not working as expected.

*Edit*

By expected, I mean: the transition being performed as a LayoutToLayout transition from one "From" collection view to the "To" collection view

Any clues of what I maybe doing wrong?

Comment: What exactly is "not working as expected"?

Comment: @Mundi The transition being perform as a LayoutToLayout transition from one "From" collection view to the "To" collection view

Comment: Is the InnerCV the root of a Navigation Controller? From the docs: "This property helps facilitate transitions between two or more collection view controllers using a navigation controller"

Comment: @GutoAraujo No. The OuterCV is the root of the navigation controller. That's why I'm calling it a non-trivial case.